# Need help getting TCP port number and IP address in C

Tags: c, sockets, ip-address

I'm trying to find a way to get my server to print its TCP Port Number and IP address but how I have it right now is producing the wrong IP, I am getting an output of 0.0.33.32. Any help is appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>

#define PORT "21467"  // the port users will be connecting to

#define BACKLOG 10   // how many pending connections queue will hold

void sigchld_handler(int s)
{
while(waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0);
}

// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
    return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
}

return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(void)
{
int sockfd, new_fd;  // listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd
struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
struct sockaddr_storage their_addr; // connector's address information
socklen_t sin_size;
struct sigaction sa;
int yes=1;
char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
int rv;

memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my IP

char hname[100];
gethostname(hname, sizeof hname);

if ((rv = getaddrinfo(hname, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
    return 1;
}
// loop through all the results and bind to the first we can
for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
    if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
            p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
        perror("server: socket");
        continue;
    }

    if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes,
            sizeof(int)) == -1) {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
        close(sockfd);
        perror("server: bind");
        continue;
    }

    break;
}

if (p == NULL)  {
    fprintf(stderr, "server: failed to bind\n");
    return 2;
}




freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure

if (listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1) {
    perror("listen");
    exit(1);
}

sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler; // reap all dead processes
sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
    perror("sigaction");
    exit(1);
}


char host[100];
char service[20];

getnameinfo(p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen, host, sizeof host, service, sizeof service, 0);
inet_ntop(p->ai_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)p->ai_addr),
        host, sizeof host);

printf("server: has TCP port number %s and IP address %s\n", service, host); 

printf("server: waiting for connections...\n");

int numbytes;
char buf[100];

while(1) {  // main accept() loop
    sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
    new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
    if (new_fd == -1) {
        perror("accept");
        continue;
    }

    inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
        get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr),
        s, sizeof s);

    //getnameinfo(get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr), sizeof get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr), NULL, NULL, service, sizeof service, 0);

    if ((numbytes = recv(new_fd, buf, 100, 0)) == -1)
        perror("recv");

    /* if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, 100, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("recv");
    exit(1);
}*/ 

    struct tm* local;
    char toClient[50];
    printf("server: received '%s'\n",buf);
    time_t curTime = time(0);
    local = localtime(&curTime);
    if(buf[0] == 't'    ){ 
        printf("server: received time request\n", s);
        sprintf(toClient, "Time: %d::%d::%d", local->tm_hour, local->tm_min, local->tm_sec);  //Seg faulting
        printf("Sent the time to the client having IP address %s and port number %s\n", s, service);
    }
    else if(buf[0] == 'd'){
        printf("server: received date request\n", s);
        sprintf(toClient, "Date: %d::%d::%d", 1900+local->tm_year, 1+local->tm_mon, local->tm_mday);
        printf("Sent the date to the client having IP address %s and port number %s\n", s, service);
    }
    else{

    }   

    if ((numbytes = send(new_fd, toClient, sizeof toClient, 0)) == -1) {
    perror("send");
    exit(1);
}
    close(new_fd);
    break; //Temporary
}


close(sockfd);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show the definition of `get_in_addr()`.  This is almost certainly a network-byte-order issue.

Comment: Can you describe the problem with more detail? Which message is wrong ("has TCP port number..."?), what exactly does it print, what exactly did you expect to see? 0.0.33.32 could come out if you try to look at  text (" !") as an IP address.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the port # is correct but the IP is coming out wrong

Comment: Besides using `getsockname` to get the actual bound address as I suggest in my answer, why are you using both `getnameinfo` _and_ `inet_ntop`? Using `getnameinfo` gives you all you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your `inet_ntop` call:

```
inet_ntop(p->ai_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)p->ai_addr),
          host, sizeof host);
```

In here you are using pointer `p` after calling

```
freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
```

You need to copy the struct `sockaddr` and `socklen_t` you got from `getaddrinfo` in some variables, or store the struct `addrinfo` for further use. Otherwise you will cause undefined behavior, like you are now experiencing. Remember, Valgrind is your friend.

Comment: Thank you, I forgot that I had made p a pointer! BTW what is Valgrind?

Comment: @Ryan Valgrind is a memory analyzer (it can do a lot of other things). Basically it will tell you when you are trying to read from or write to invalid memory locations, ie. not allocated or freed memory. Find more about it here: (link)[http://valgrind.org/]

Answer (score 6):

What you might need to use is the [`getsockname`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getsockname) function:

```
struct sockaddr_storage my_addr;
socklen_t my_addr_len = sizeof(my_addr);
if (getsockname(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &my_addr, &my_addr_len) != -1)
{
#ifndef NI_MAXHOST
# define NI_MAXHOST 1025
#endif
#ifndef NI_MAXSERV
# define NI_MAXSERV 32
#endif

    char host[NI_MAXHOST];
    char serv[NI_MAXSERV];

    if (getnameinfo((const struct sockaddr *) &my_addr, my_addr.ss_len,
                    host, sizeof(host),
                    serv, sizeof(serv), 0) == 0)
    {
        printf("Host address: %s, host service: %s\n", host, serv);
    }
}
```

Comment: The application tries to be IPv6 aware. So `struct sockaddr_in` will be too short for that... In contrast, `struct sockaddr_storage` is intended to be large enough for all purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the other answers (getsockname) is probably already what you need.

I just would like to highlight one of the best sources available to understanding network programming:

**[Beej's guide to network programming](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/)**

- it's reasonably short, you work through it within 1 hour
- works for both, windows and linux (and unix etc...)
- explains the concepts behind in the necessary detail (no fuss where not necessary)