# Pass along client ip address

Tags: c++, c, networking, zeromq

So I have a system using ZeroMQ as the message controller and because it doesn't allow you to find information about a clients address that is connecting or sending messages I need to pass in self identifying information containing port and ip address of the node. However I'm not sure the best way of doing this.

I'm stuck because if they connect using an internal ip address for the network I would obviously need to use that ip address but if its going over WAN then I need the public ip address. What is the best way of communicating the ip address of the machine without knowing whether or not you are connecting to a local machine or a machine over WAN

Comment: ***[Look Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461382/need-help-getting-tcp-port-number-and-ip-address-in-c)***

Comment: I don't have access to the socket itself it is handled by zeromq

Comment: This is pretty much the problem addressed by protocols like [TURN](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5766) and [STUN](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5389).